# Distance of a point to a finite union of polyhedra

Tags: geometry, reference-request, algorithms, polyhedra, quadratic-programming

Given a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a finite union of (possibly overlapping) polyhedra $$ S = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d :\bigvee_{i=1}^m \bigwedge_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x \leq b_i \right\} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d :\bigvee_{i=1}^m A_i x \leq b_i \right\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^m \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : A_i x \leq b_i \right\}$$ where $a_{ij}$ is a vector, how can the distance of $p$ to the possibly non-convex set $S$ be computed? If $p \notin S$, the distance is the length of the shortest ray from $p$ to the boundary of $S$. If $p \in S$, the distance is the length of the shortest ray from $p$ to the boundary of $S$ where the ray may not leave $S$. Which algorithms are known to compute this distance? Are there implementations?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Quadratic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) (QP) problem. "QP is a special type of mathematical optimization problem — specifically, the problem of optimizing (minimizing or maximizing) a quadratic function of several variables subject to linear constraints on these variables. It is a particular type of nonlinear programming".

Comment: Could you give a pointer to the formulation you have in mind. A union of polyhedra can also be represented as mixed integer linear problem but it is not clear to me how to express the distance function properly in this framework.

Comment: @Mathpol So you are given not *one* set $S$ of the form $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \forall i\, A_ix \leq b_i\}$ (which is convex) but a union of *several* such sets? Or you are given $S$ to be a union of half-spaces of the form $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \leq b\}$ (which may be not convex)?

Comment: Good point. My notation was not good. I fixed it above. What I mean is that $S$ is the set of all points that are contained in at least one of the the convex polyhedra, i.e., it is the disjunction of polyhedra which is in general non-convex.

Comment: I have to go now, but I remark that to find a (mininal)  distance $d$ from the point $p$ to a union $\bigcup S_i$ of convex sets $S_i=\bigcap_{j=1}^{m_i} \{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid A_{i,j}x\le b_{i,j}\}$ it suffices to find by QP a (minimal) distance $d_i$ from the point $p$ to a set $ S_i$ for each $i$. Then $d=\min d_i$.

Comment: That is true if $p \notin \bigcup S_i$ but it is not true otherwise since two polyhedra may overlap, i.e., I don't assume they are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Yes, this is written in your question, but, strictly speaking,  this is not the distance from $p$ to the $S$ (which is $0$, because $p$ belongs to $S$), but a distance from $p$ to the complement $S^c=\Bbb R^n\setminus S$, that is a length of the shortest *segment* from $p$ to the boundary of $S$, right? If so, then since in the current edition of your question $S$ is a union of (closed) halfspaces, its complement  $S^c$ is an intersection of (open) halfspaces, that is convex, and we still can found the distance from $p$ to $S^c$ by  QP.

Comment: You are right that I could rephrase the question of the shortest distance of a point within S to its boundary as the distance of the point to the complement of S. However, S is a union of conjunctions of halfspaces not just a union of halfspaces. Nevertheless, the complement of a union of polyhedra (conjunction of halfspaces) is still a union of polyhedra, except if one is closed, the other one is open. Hence, I think optimization is not needed, it suffices to pick the minimum among all distances to halfspaces.